# Report Builder: How to set height of multiple text boxes same time

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am working with Report Builder in SQL Server 2016.

I have multiple text boxes say `Textbox1`, `Textbox2` and `Textbox3` of different heights. I want them to have same height. I can do that by selecting each of them one by one, going to its properties and set the value of `Height` property under `Size`.

But what if I want to set the height of all of them at once? How can I do that? I selected all of them, then go into properties, but under `Size` the `Height` property is not visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Home > Align** and check if there is a option which suits your case. If not then I guess you have to do it for each textbox in the properties.